# How to move millions of file to another file in the same container in Azure Blob Storage?

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

We have millions of record (both parquet and json files) in Azure Blob Storage as the structure of:

/RecordName/Year/Month/Day/Hour/ParquetOrJsonFiles.parquetOrjson

There are approx. 5 Million files in that structure and I want to reshape the folder path as:

/Year/Month/Day/Hour/RecordName/ParquetOrJsonFiles.parquetOrjson

I've created a basic script in DataBricks python notebook like this:
ps: Container was already mounted in my workspace.

```
import os

target_file = '/dbfs/containername/RecordName/Year/Month/Day/Hour/ParquetOrJsonFiles.parquetOrjson'
destination_file = '/dbfs/Year/Month/Day/Hour/RecordName/ParquetOrJsonFiles.parquetOrjson'

os.rename(target_file, destination_file)
```

However this script works very slowly. Is there any way to faster moving?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, there is not any REST API of Azure Blob Storage to support renaming opertion for a blob, so the real operations for renaming a blob is first to copy it and then to delete it. The `os.rename` function operating in `dbfs` also is to do the copy and delete operation in order. That's the real reason to make your script slow.

The solution using REST APIs is first to do [`Copy Blob From URL`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/copy-blob-from-url) for each blob in a container, and then to do [`Delete Blob`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delete-blob) for all original blobs within a [`Blob Batch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/blob-batch).

Here is my sample code using the functions `start_copy_from_url`, `delete_blobs`  of the latest Azure Storage SDK for Python [(v12)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python) which be installed via `pip install azure-storage-blob`.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

account_name = '<your account name>'
account_key = '<your account key>'
connection_string = f"AccountName={account_name};AccountKey={account_key};EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net;DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)

container_name = '<your container name>'

container_client = blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)

blobs = list(container.list_blobs())

# Copy all blobs with a new name to the same container
for blob in blobs:
    blob_name = blob.name
    source_url = f"https://{account_name}.blob.core.windows.net/{container_name}/{blob_name}"
    record_name, year, month, day, hour, name = blob_name.split('/')
    new_blob_name = f'{year}/{month}/{day}/{hour}/{record_name}/name'
    copied_blob = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name, new_blob_name)
    copied_blob.start_copy_from_url(source_url)

# Delete all original blobs
delete_blob_list = [b.name for b in blobs]
container_client.delete_blobs(*delete_blob_list)
```

Comment: Does the python version of start_copy run server side like the C# version does as this is infinitely faster then the old copy operation. If it doesn't I'd recommend using the AZCopy tool as that will do the copies server side.

Comment: missing 'container'